# How to format all numbers in a table in r using kable?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

[image: Code output]

I need to be able to reduce or simplify the numbers in this table. I want only up to 4 decimal places shown and if possible only integers if the number is a whole number. How would I accomplish this?

```
library(kableExtra)
x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
y = x/2
z = x/3
a = data.frame(x, y, z)
b = t(a)
c = kable(b, "html", align = "c") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

Comment: @eipi10 - the `digits` argument by itself is insufficient to print `x` with no decimals.

Answer (score 11):

Use the `format()` function to convert the data to the minimum number of decimals needed to render the data. Using the code from the original post:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
y = x/2
z = x/3

a = data.frame(x = format(x,digits=4,nsmall = 0), 
               y = format(y,digits=4,nsmall = 0), 
               z = format(z,digits = 4,nsmall = 0))
b = t(a)
c = kable(b, "html", align = "c") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

...and the output:

[image]

Incorporating Martin Schmelzer's comments, a tidyverse version of the same solution looks like this.

```
# tidyverse alternative
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
y = x/2
z = x/3
data.frame(x,y,z) %>% 
   mutate_if(is.numeric, format, digits=4,nsmall = 0) %>% t(.) %>% kable(.,"html",align = "c") %>% 
   kable_styling(full_width = F) -> c
```

Comment: `df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, format, digits=4) %>% kable` makes life easier.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer - your code is missing the `nsmall` argument and the `t(.)` function in the pipeline, but I incorporated those items and added the tidyverse version to the answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Well aware of what was missing. Since I only commented without any output I saw no need for that since the focus was on conditional mutation.